undefined symbol: sqlite3_deserialize in Jupyter notebook - Visual Studio Code
I use remote development plug-in in visual studio because I run code on server. When I try to run any line of code in interactive window the following error occurs:
ImportError: /home/user/anaconda3/envs/geo/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-312-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: sqlite3_deserialize. 

I have already intalled Ipykernel and Jupyter plug in.
I use Ubuntu 22.04, python 3.12.2
Am I missing something?

By inspecting the version of sqlite3 installed on my conda environment using sqlite3 --version I found out that the version was 3.22. My ultimate goal was to install gdal, but as it turned out there some incompatibilities between them.
I fix it by using:
- sqlite 2.6.0
- gdal 3.9.2
- python 3.12.6

on ubuntu 24.04

I run into the same error in Python3.11.9. I noticed when I installed rapids my Python was downgraded to 3.11.8 as well as sqlite. Tried upgrading python again to 3.11.9, but that didn't work. Any way to reinstall sqlite maybe?

I solved this error by updating the SQLite and then rebuilding my python environment. Or in your case you can create a new environment.
As per my understanding the older version doesn't have serialize functionality in it. Also please make sure that your environment and anaconda have the same version of SQLite.
